# Why is Analytic Sessions always ZERO?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

MFP 7.1 Studio - Very simple code in main.js

```
function wlCommonInit() {
    WL.Client.connect({
    onSuccess: function() {alert ("OK");},
    onFailure: function (string) {alert ("fail" + string);}
    });
}

var event={buttonPress: 'buttonc'};
WL.Analytics.log (event, "customer event");
WL.Analytics.send();
```

So I am getting things in the console.
I see this bar shows up saying I ran it at 7 pm (that's right I ran it just now)
[image]

And this session shows up as well. Good..
[image]

And now looks at all the Sessions.  It's zero.  Please assist.  Thanks.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In 7.1, a new Session-Independent Mode was introduced, and is turned on by default. Please read more about session-independent mode [here](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/devref/c_overview_session_indep.html?lang=en).

Being on session independent means that your server needs to issue a token to start a session. If you have no security enabled on your application then your server will never start a session. To see how this works it is best to set up something basic like our [form based authentication](https://github.com/MobileFirst-Platform-Developer-Center/FormBasedAuth).

To disable session independent mode:

If you go into your project's "worklight.properties" file, set (or change) these values:

```
mfp.session.independent=false
mfp.attrStore.type=HttpSession
```

and then rebuild/deploy your project, it should work.